# Odoo v10 open html report fail

Tags: odoo-10

If I would like to print a report directly to HTML Odoo is crashing. I can see the Report but I can't do nothing...
Here is the screen.

[Endless Loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j9AF.png)

I am using Odoo v10 and installed a fresh version on a different server. There is also the same problem. Does anybody no a solution? Thank you

Comment: You should see transactions in your postgre db. In my opinion, this thing is a dead lock...or you have too many data to process in your report, in this case this thing is normal. Can you check the transactions?

Comment: There are no errors in the postgresql log, and also in the odoo log.
I only got the message of 'longpolling' in nginx... But this should be the result of a server time out? am I right?

Comment: According to my experiences, postgresql log doesnt contain any error about dead lock. But you can check it manually. eq with this basic sql query: `SELECT * FROM pg_locks pl LEFT JOIN pg_stat_activity psa
    ON pl.pid = psa.pid;`

Comment: I can see no problem there. There is no change if I execute this command during the "printing" or "not printing". 
But maybe this information will help you, that when there is no "wkhtmltopdf" installed, the html works perfectly fine. But I also tried other wkhtml-installtions... I have also the same problem when I used a fresh installation of Odoo 10